# Google Cloud Storage file compress/decompress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

.tgz compressed file uploaded to GCS.

Can I file decompress from the GCS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not in general.

You could upload it as a .tar file with http content-encoding gzip (stored on metadata as well), and then the compression can be removed on the fly, depending on the client request. Though note that this has implications for range requests, among other things (full documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding)). Either way, GCS can't unpack the tar archive.

Comment: the link you shared is broken.

Comment: Sorry, copy&paste mishap. Fixed now